# Syder IDE: How to change the default alignment for line continuation in the editor?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I am using Spyder on a Linux server but find the default alignment for line continuation not to my liking. I looked around in the Preference settings but did not see relevant options. Does anyone know how to change this?

The following snippet shows what I meant:

```
# Spyder default:
a = (
        Some long statement
        )

# What I want:
a = (
    Some long statement
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder developer here*) There's no way to change the alignment to fit users likings, sorry.